# Include file and if doesn't load redirect to another page

Tags: php

I know may be is silly question and I know how to redirect to another page with meta/js but is it possible to include file like this

```
include 'file.php';
```

and if after X seconds `file.php` doesn't load to redirect visitor to another page?

Comment: `include` will return false and raise a warning on failure, see docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-157

Comment: You can't do `x seconds and so something` in PHP though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
if(!file_exists($file)){
    // redirect here
}else{
    include($file);
}
```

Comment: Working too and will ask you same question - is it possible to put here some timer or something to not redirect right away but to try/wait 10sec?

Comment: `header('refresh: 10; url=url');` this?

Comment: you can do this: `if(!file_exists($file){ echo "<META http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://google.com"/>"; die; }`

Answer (score 3):

Well before loading/including file.php, you can check if file does exists or not. Check this link [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php). In case if it does not exists then redirect to your desired page. Check this link [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

As per your requirement below:

> Is it possible to put here some timer or something to not redirect right away?

Only thing I came to understand that you want to show something user that page is not being loaded and its about to redirect to another page. Even if you use sleep it will just delay the process and will not show anything to user and after that delay it will redirect right away.

***In case if you want to show user some text or notification*** you can do it like this.

```
<?php
if(!file_exists($file)){
    include('Notification_File.php');
}else{
    include($file);
    // include code regarding to this page if $file is existed
}
?>
```

And in your Notification_File.php file you can do something like this.

```
<div>
    Unable to load regarding file.
</div>

<script>
    setTimeout(redirectPage, 5000);
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should provide code sample instead of only providing links :)

Comment: Agree with you DarkBee.. But its not that much of complex problem. Will it not good to have just guidelines and person can do and understand by himself rather than just copying and pasting code...

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the return value of the include

```
if ((include 'file.php') == false) {
    header('Location: ' . $url);
}
```

Comment: It is working. Just is it possible to put here some timer or something to not redirect right away?

Comment: Well you could add a `sleep` statement to delay execution, but I don't see why you'd want that

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = '/path/to/file.php';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    include $filename;
} else {
    header( "refresh:5;url=your_url.php" );
}
```

or you can use javascript for redirection

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = 'http://your_site.com/your_url.php';
},5000);
```